# Tracking Claims as they go from New to Approved to Processed in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have df1 and df2 below:

**df1:**

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = [('2021-04-27', 'A') ,
           ('2021-04-28', 'A'),
           ('2021-04-29', 'A'),
           ('2021-04-30', 'A'),
           ('2021-05-01', 'A'),
           ('2021-05-02', 'A'),
           ('2021-05-03', 'A'),
           ('2021-05-04', 'A'),
           ('2021-05-05', 'A'),
           ('2021-05-06', 'A'),
           ('2021-05-07', 'A'),
           ('2021-05-08', 'A'),
           ('2021-05-09', 'A')
            ]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=['Date', 'Group'])
```

and:

**df2:**

```py
df2 =  [(80, '2021-04-27', 'NA', '2021-04-27', 'A'),
           (90, '2021-04-28', 'NA', '2021-04-28', 'A'),
           (100, '2021-04-29', 'NA', '2021-04-29', 'A'),
           (206, '2021-04-30', '2021-04-30', '2021-04-30' , 'A') ,
           (629, '2021-04-30', '2021-04-30', '2021-04-30', 'A'),
           (4000, '2021-04-30', '2021-04-30', '2021-04-30', 'A'),
           (4001, '2021-05-01', '2021-05-01', 'NA' , 'A'),
           (4002, '2021-05-01', '2021-05-01', '2021-05-01', 'A'),
           (4003, '2021-05-03', '2021-05-03', '2021-05-03', 'A'),
           (4004, '2021-05-03', '2021-05-03', '2021-05-03', 'A'),
           (4005, '2021-05-03', '2021-05-03', '2021-05-06', 'A'),
           (4006, '2021-05-03', '2021-05-03', '2021-05-06', 'A'),
           (4007, '2021-05-04', '2021-05-04', '2021-05-04', 'A'),
           (4008, '2021-05-04', '2021-05-04', '2021-05-04', 'A')
            ]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns=['ClaimID', 'New', 'Approved', 'Processed', 'Group'])
```

**Desired output:**

```py
df3 = [('2021-04-27', 1, 0, 1, 'A'),
           ('2021-04-28', 1, 0, 1, 'A'),
           ('2021-04-29', 1, 0, 1, 'A'),
           ('2021-04-30', 3, 3, 3, 'A'),
           ('2021-05-01', 2, 2, 1, 'A'),
           ('2021-05-02', 0, 1, 0, 'A'),
           ('2021-05-03', 4, 5, 2, 'A'),
           ('2021-05-04', 2, 5, 2, 'A'),
           ('2021-05-05', 0, 3, 0, 'A'),
           ('2021-05-06', 0, 3, 2, 'A'),
           ('2021-05-07', 0, 1, 0, 'A'),
           ('2021-05-08', 0, 1, 0, 'A'),
           ('2021-05-09', 0, 1, 0, 'A')
            ]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df3, columns=['Date', 'New', 'Approved', 'Processed', 'Group'])
```

A few conditions that this follows:

1. If a claim is approved and processed on the same day then both, approved and processed, in df3 should show the number of approved and processed on that day and then reset to 0 or the number of app/proc on the next day. For example, on 2021-04-30, there were 3 approved and processed on the same day in df2 so df3 shows 3 and 3, respectively and then they reset to the number app/proc on the next day.
2. If more are approved than processed on a certain day, the remaining approved should carry over to the next day. For example, on 2021-05-01 2 were approved but only 1 was processed. In df2, we can see that the claim was in fact never processed (NA) so that remainder of 1 should stay for the rest of df3.
3. If there are multiple approved claims and they are processed on different days then the claims processed later than the approved date should carry over until they reach the processed date. For example, 2 approved claims on 2021-05-03 are processed on the same day and 2 are process on 2021-05-06. Those 2 processed on 2021-05-06 should carry over until Approved reaches 2021-05-06.
4. Approved claims should not technically start counting until the first instance of Approved occurs. Hence why Approved is 0, 0, 0 for 4/27-4/29.

Any help would be appreciated and I can clarify as needed.

Comment: Why do you need `df1` here?

Comment: Then it's not clear to me if you can have the same claim id on another day/row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain df3 by using 2 for loops to fill the zero's in an empty `df3`, here called `df_out`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# make df_out with the df1.Date column as index, a (df1.nrows x 3) np.array 
# of zeros and the df1.Group column
df_out = pd.concat([
    df1.Date, 
    pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((df1.shape[0], 3), dtype=int),
                columns=["New", "Approved", "Processed"]),
    df1.Group], axis=1).set_index("Date")


# loop through df2, add a 1 to the cell in df_out that corresponds
# to the date and status of the claim (ignore the NA's)
for index, claim in df2.iterrows():
    for status in ["New", "Approved", "Processed"]:
        date = claim[status]
        if date != "NA":
            df_out.loc[(date, status)] += 1

# loop through df_out, and for every date check if there are
# approved but unprocessed entries. carry the positive
# difference to the next row, add them to the approved entries
carry = 0
for date, row in df_out.iterrows():
    app, prc = row["Approved"] + carry, row["Processed"]
    carry = max(0, app - prc)
    df_out.loc[date, "Approved"] = app

# make the date index a column again, reset to standard index
df_out.reset_index(inplace=True)

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
          Date  New  Approved  Processed Group
0   2021-04-27    1         0          1     A
1   2021-04-28    1         0          1     A
2   2021-04-29    1         0          1     A
3   2021-04-30    3         3          3     A
4   2021-05-01    2         2          1     A
5   2021-05-02    0         1          0     A
6   2021-05-03    4         5          2     A
7   2021-05-04    2         5          2     A
8   2021-05-05    0         3          0     A
9   2021-05-06    0         3          2     A
10  2021-05-07    0         1          0     A
11  2021-05-08    0         1          0     A
12  2021-05-09    0         1          0     A
```